# HIVEql statement for listing all available functions

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

At my work we are limited in which functions are available in our HIVEql environment. Is there a statement that can be run that will list all of the available functions? For example:

SELECT * FROM all_available_functions;

Comment: If you are looking for suggestion like thing as IDE. You can use hue UI for hadoop.
http://demo.gethue.com/beeswax/execute

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `SHOW FUNCTIONS` command. It will list all Hive functions and operators.

```
hive>SHOW FUNCTIONS;
hive>DESCRIBE FUNCTION <function_name>;
hive>DESCRIBE FUNCTION EXTENDED <function_name>;
```